# Uploaded and not converted files do not appear in the document feed in Google Docs

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I trying to retrieve a complete list of files from a given directory with code like this

```
uri = '%s' % fentry.content.src
feed = gd_client.GetDocumentListFeed(uri=uri)
for r in feed.entry:
    print r.title.text.decode("utf-8")
```

It works except that it only return "real" Google Documents files and does not return files, which were uploaded but not converted, e.g. *.docx files.

Is there any way to get complete list of files in given directory?

Answer (score 1):

I have the suspicion that you are using a wrong uri. Read here about the different options you have:

http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ListDocs

Comment: I've tried different feed URLs. Following do not work:
/feeds/documents/private/full?showfolders=true
 http://docs.google.com/feeds/folders/private/full/folder:folderID

Comment: I haven't worked with the Google Docs API myself, so it's just an assumption. Since you are recieving a list of documents, the rest of your code seems ok...What about this one? https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3Afolder_id/contents

Comment: This one does not work (although it is in the documentation) - returns 400:Invalid request URI